# Error subtracting months from a $date in tibble

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I found that you can use `%m-% months(12)` to subtract months from a date variable. But when trying to do that on my object below called `lastmonth` it doesn't work.

```
tibble [1 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ date: Date[1:1], format: "2022-09-01"
```

I want to do this:

```
monthlastyr <- lastmonth %m-% months(12)
```

**Error I get:**

*Error in as.POSIXlt.default(force_tz(object, tzone = "UTC")) :
do not know how to convert 'force_tz(object, tzone = "UTC")' to class “POSIXlt”
In addition: Warning message:
tz(): Don't know how to compute timezone for object of class tbl_df/tbl/data.frame; returning "UTC".*

What's going on?

Comment: Did you mean `lastmonth$date %m-% months(12)`? You need to apply the subtraction to the column with date values, not the entire data.frame itself.

Comment: Yes that worked like a charm - thanks!
I can filter the df both with my data.frame (or tibble) and the value we just created - but trying to combine with this code it doesn't work, what now?
```
> dfbef <- filter(dfbef, date == monthlastyr | lastmonth)
Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = date == monthlastyr | lastmonth`.
Caused by error in `Ops.Date()`:
! | not defined for "Date" objects
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to do. That seems like a new question. Are you trying to match once of two dates? Because that's the wrong syntax. You can't just put the "or" on the value side. Proper R syntax is more like `filter(dfbef, date == monthlastyr | data==lastmonth)`

Comment: Yes it was a follow-up questions, I'll try another way or I get back with a new question so it's clearer - thanks!